# Structural variant calling for low-coverage PacBio data

Tags: structural-variation, long-reads, pacbio

PacBio is selling ~10x PacBio SEQUEL long reads as an upgrade to Illumina data for SV discovery.

In a clinical setting, the main requirements are proper sensitivity and specificity but also the processing of cohorts, at least families. This requires a genotyping step, such that it can be identified whether a given variant is shared by two or more individuals or whether it is not.

What are the tools of the trade for this task?

As having 50-60x PacBio reads is not an option from a economic point of view, one has to make do with 10x coverage.

Answer (score 2):

There is an evaluation of PB Honey and Sniffles algorithms for low coverage PacBio datasets in [this preprint](http://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/12/17/092544.full.pdf+html) and another evaluation is shown on [this poster](http://www.pacb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016-ashg-poster-andrew-carroll-dnanexus.pdf). Both reports agree that optimal is (surprisingly) combination of [PB Honey](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pb-jelly/) and [Sniffles](https://github.com/fritzsedlazeck/Sniffles).

Author of Sniffles have benchmarked Sniffles against PB Honey, where he shown that Sniffles performs significantly better. Take a look on [this presentation (slide 15)](http://schatzlab.cshl.edu/presentations/2016/2016.10.28.BIODATA.PacBioSV.pdf).

Another option is [SMRT-SV](https://github.com/EichlerLab/pacbio_variant_caller), but I am not aware of any benchmarking.

Comment: SMRT-SV uses assembly-quality coverage of PB reads and sadly of low use. PB Honey and Sniffles are essentially useless for clinical germline studies as neither supports multi-sample calling and when comparing calls from both tools on patients where we also had Illumina X Ten genomes showed promise in PB data but severe problems with existing tools.

Comment: I can imagine that if the SV calls would take into account all the family data in one go, the results would be more reliable. However is it really a problem to do variant calls individually and then compare / merge them? I would guess that it would be still better than Illumina...

Comment: Has anyone successfully used either of these programs on MinION generated data?

Comment: @MatthewBashton for this you should open a new question...

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of the following (very few and suboptimal) options:

- [Sniffles](https://github.com/fritzsedlazeck/Sniffles/releases) -- sadly not very reliable in my experience, also no genotyping step or multi-sample support
- [PB Honey](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-180) -- no genotyping step or multi-sample support